# Inner joining multiple tables using JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get all asset of a user but it is several tables apart and I'm having trouble writing a CriteriaBuilder for it.

```
@Entity
public class Asset {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_branch_id")
    private CompanyBranch companyBranch;
}

@Entity
public class CompanyBranch {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyBranch")
    private Set<Asset> assets;
}

@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "companies")
    private Set<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<CompanyBranch> companyBranches;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        schema = "User",
        name = "user_company",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Company> companies;
}
```

I want to be able to create a CriteriaBuilder similar to how this SQL statement looks:

```
SELECT a.* FROM asset a
INNER JOIN company_branch b ON a.company_branch_id = b.id
INNER JOIN company c ON b.company_id = c.id
INNER JOIN user_company d ON c.id = d.company_id
WHERE d.user_id = ?
```

What's the proper way to write my CriteriaBuilder code in order to retrieve the correct result?

This is my code so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Root<Asset> assetRoot = query.from(Asset.class);
Join<Asset, CompanyBranch> companyBranchJoin = assetRoot.join("companyBranch", JoinType.INNER);
Join<CompanyBranch, Company> companyJoin = assetRoot.join("company", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Company, User> userJoin = assetRoot.join("users", JoinType.INNER);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(userJoin.get("UserId"), userId);

query.where(predicate);
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've added code that I tried that doesn't work.